# Where does an ATmega328p go on the STK500?

Tags: avr, programmer

My STK500 manual doesn't tell me, where does an ATmega328p go on the STK500?

Comment: There are two potential sockets on the board.

Answer (score 1):

The ATmega328p can be programmed on the STK500 in the green socket into which it fits.

Answer (score 0):

In whichever socket it fits. Make sure the device notch matches that of the socket. The colour code tells you which sockets are connected to which programming headers. The jumpers are for all of them.

Comment: There are two potential choices. I should just check that the socket I want to try doesn't swap VCC and GND and it will probably be fine.